# Boot happens twice even if I delete the first option in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, uefi, efibootmgr

When I power on my notebook it looks like it is doing the boot twice.

It's happening exactly like in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yLrrstUyKo&lc=z22qvxq4yzudz3ewh04t1aokgk1xmtl5lqyo3rlmpci1rk0h00410)

I've run the command `sudo efibootmgr -v`

And here is my output:

```
BootCurrent: 000A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0008,0001,000A
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a2441c54-8066-424c-8ac9-cfc6bf1a3298,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001  usb   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,GPT,2c3e2079-83f2-4468-b367-e11b575434e5,0x800,0xee83df)
Boot0007  Onboard NIC(IPV4) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e454e82dc133,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0008  Onboard NIC(IPV6) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e454e82dc133,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot000A* UEFI: KINGSTON SA2000M8500G, Partition 1  HD(1,GPT,a2441c54-8066-424c-8ac9-cfc6bf1a3298,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
Boot0010* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0011* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0012* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0013* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Realtek PXE B03 D00,0x0)..BO
Boot0016* UEFI: WDC WD10SPZX-75Z10T2, Partition 1   HD(1,GPT,835565fb-6510-4593-8f46-3d9612ab3c97,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
```

I suspect that it is trying to first boot the Boot0000 and the 0000 boot tries to find the ubuntu in usb PciRoot and can't find it...

So after it can't find that, 000A, which is my SSD with Ubuntu installed, is being used (the first line of the output shows this entry).

To delete I've run:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

So I've tried to delete the first option of Ubuntu, and after I restart the notebook, the problem appears again and the first option which I've deleted appears again..

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I don't have dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to default to using this file:

```
\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Which then loads this file:

```
\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi
```

This is a sure sign that Secure Boot is enabled. Secure Boot will only load a bootloader signed by Microsoft. You will have to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS / UEFI firmware before your computer will stop defaulting to shimx64.efi.

Comment: after trying this the problems still happens, and when I restart the first option which I had deleted appears again..

Comment: @IgorAgueme That's very strange. What is the output now of efibootmgr?
Also you may try to make the 0000 boot inactive first (the asterisk beside the number means it is currently active):
efibootmgr -b 0000 -A
Then delete it and change the boot order.

Comment: I've answered above to put a snippet with output

Comment: @IgorAgueme is Secure Boot enabled in your BIOS? Usually that's the only reason the shimx64.efi is needed. Find the Secure Boot setting and disable it.

Comment: @IgorAgueme - see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I didnt receive the notification, the secure mode os disabled.. I took a picture https://ibb.co/nL2tbyJ

Comment: any others idea?

Comment: Was this originally a dual-boot system, or was secure boot enabled when you first installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutly strange and doesn't make any sense...

After I've turned the first option inactive the problem still happens but now look how do output lookslike

```
BootCurrent: 000A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,000A,000C,000D
Boot0000  ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a2441c54-8066-424c-8ac9-cfc6bf1a3298,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a2441c54-8066-424c-8ac9-cfc6bf1a3298,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000A* UEFI: KINGSTON SA2000M8500G, Partition 1  HD(1,GPT,a2441c54-8066-424c-8ac9-cfc6bf1a3298,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
Boot000C* Onboard NIC(IPV4) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e454e82dc133,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot000D* Onboard NIC(IPV6) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e454e82dc133,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot0010* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0011* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)..BO
Boot0012* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0013* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Realtek PXE B03 D00,0x0)..BO
Boot0016* UEFI: WDC WD10SPZX-75Z10T2, Partition 1   HD(1,GPT,835565fb-6510-4593-8f46-3d9612ab3c97,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
```

It duplicate and force the first option to happen